# On the equation $\sqrt{x^2-9}=\frac{2(x+3)}{(x-3)^2}-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve the equation

$$\sqrt{x^2-9}=\frac{2(x+3)}{(x-3)^2}-x \tag{1}$$

*Attempt:* I have rewritten the equation as

\begin{align*} 
\sqrt{x^2-9} = \frac{2(x+3)}{\left (x-3 \right )^2}-x &\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x^2-9} = \frac{2(x+3)-x\left ( x-3 \right )^2}{\left ( x-3 \right )^2} \\ 
&\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x^2-9} = - \frac{x^3-6x^2+7x-6}{\left ( x-3 \right )^2} \\ &\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{x^2-9} = \frac{2}{x-3} -x + \frac{12}{\left ( x-3 \right )^2} 
\end{align*}

This seems manageable (?) but I do not know how to proceed. The solution is $x=8-\sqrt{13}$ as suggested by Mr. Wolfy. I have no idea how to get it.

In the mean time if we square $(1)$ all 6th powers are simplified and we are left with

$$5x^4-96x^3+526x^2-105x+765=0$$

Trying to factorising it we get with some luck that

$$(x^2-16x+51)(5x^2-16x+15) =0$$

and we have to solve this. This is easy but we have to take into account the restriction

$$ -x^3+6x^2-7x+6\geq 0 $$

Comment: When you have found the “possible” roots, check if they satisfy the restriction.

Comment: You can also check them with a direct substitution into the original equation. If you get wrong identity you can discharge them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference of two squares identity and its Conjugates can help:

$\sqrt{x^2-9} = \frac{2(x+3)}{(x-3)^2} - x$

$(x-3)^2(\sqrt{x^2-9} + x) = 2(x+3)$

$(x-3)^2(\sqrt{x^2-9} + x)(\sqrt{x^2-9} - x) = 2(x+3)(\sqrt{x^2-9} - x)$

$(x-3)^2(x^2-9 - x^2) = 2(x+3)(\sqrt{x^2-9} - x)$

$-9(x-3)^2 = 2(x+3)(\sqrt{x^2-9} - x)$

$\frac{-9(x-3)^2}{2(x+3)} = \sqrt{x^2-9} - x$

$\frac{-9(x-3)^2}{2(x+3)} + x = \sqrt{x^2-9}$

We achieve new equation for $\sqrt{x^2-9}, \ $ and so we can equal this one to the first equation:

$\frac{-9(x-3)^2}{2(x+3)} + x = \sqrt{x^2-9} = \frac{2(x+3)}{(x-3)^2} - x$

$\frac{-9(x-3)^2}{2(x+3)} + x = \frac{2(x+3)}{(x-3)^2} - x$

Now we get ride of radicals, so we can solve it without any restriction caused by squaring.

Comment: Nice! The last equation has two roots though $8\pm \sqrt{13}$ so we have to check which one satisfies the initial one!

Comment: @Tolaso Every roots of last equation satisfy the initial one except roots of $\sqrt{x^2-9}-x=0$, that is empty set!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $\sqrt{x^2-9}=3\tan2t\ge0,0\le2t<\dfrac\pi2$

$x=3\sec2t$

$$3(\tan2t+\sec2t)=\dfrac{6(\sec2t+1)}{9(\sec2t-1)^2}$$

$$3(\sin2t+1)=\dfrac{2(1+\cos2t)}{3(1-\cos2t)^2}$$

Set $\tan t=u$

$$\dfrac{9(1+u)^2}{1+u^2}=\dfrac{4(1+u^2)^2}{4(1+u^2)u^4}$$

$$\iff9(1+u)^2u^4=(1+u^2)^2$$

As $u=\tan t\ge0$

$$\implies3(1+u)u^2=1+u^2$$

$$3u^3+2u^2-1=0$$

Use [Cardano's method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3357131/on-the-equation-sqrtx2-9-frac2x3x-32-x/3357223#3357223)

Comment: Thank you mate!